# How do I make authenticated HTTP GET request with Spring schedule service

Tags: java, spring, get, httprequest, scheduled-tasks

In ruby I can make a GET request with username and password by doing:

```
    uri = URI('http://192.00.00.00')

    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    req.basic_auth 'username', 'password'     

    res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
         http.request(req)
    }
```

Right now I am trying to make a GET request to my server that requires an username and password using Java and Spring.  How does the above code translates to Java?

Also, if I want to make the request every 5 seconds, should I simply have the java code inside the block below?

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void httpRequest() {
    //java code here
}
```

Comment: Don't ask two unrelated questions in one. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: One question is how to do GET with authentication, the other one is how to schedule an operation every X seconds. And you can easily find answers for both.